# Limit of Sequence is 1 if $\alpha>\beta>\gamma$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_{n+1}$=$\frac{\alpha x_n^2+\beta x_n(1-x_n)}{\alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2}$ be a sequence, where $0\leq \alpha,\beta,\gamma\leq 1$. $0<x_0<1$

Suppose $\alpha>\beta>\gamma$ then show that $<x_n>$ converge to 1.

My approach. I showed $0<x_n<1\ \forall n$, Then if I am able to show it is monotonically increasing then it will converge to 1 by Monotone Convergence Theorem. After calculations I am getting $x_{n+1}\geq x_n^2+\frac{\beta}{\alpha} x_n(1-x_n)$. Any suggestions?

The second part of the questions says, if $\alpha <\beta<\gamma$ then $<x_n>$ converges to zero. I am guessing it will follow the same pattern as above.

Comment: Just note, I think the place you reach will not lead you to  $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$ since  $[x_n^2+\frac{\beta}{\alpha} x_n(1-x_n) ] - x_n  = \frac{\beta}{\alpha} x_n(1-x_n)   - x_n( 1-x_n) =  x_n(1-x_n)( \frac{\beta}{\alpha} - 1)  < 0  $ since  $ \alpha > \beta $  so  $ \frac{\beta}{\alpha} < 1 $.  so  $x_n^2+\frac{\beta}{\alpha} x_n(1-x_n)  <  x_n $ !

Comment: Any idea on how to proceed or what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that $<x_n>$ converges to $1$, enough to show that it is increasing, since it is bounded above by $1$. So , required to show  $$ x_{n+1} \geq  x_n$$
We have: 
$$x_{n+1}=  x_n\Big[  \frac{\alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n)}{\alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2}  \Big]$$
So it is enough to show  that  $$ \frac{\alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n)}{\alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2} \geq 1 $$
i.e. $$ \alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n)  \geq  \alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2  $$ i.e. 
$$ \Big[\alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n)\Big]  - \Big[\alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2 \Big] \geq   0 $$
Indeed

\begin{align} 
\Big[\alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n)\Big]  - \Big[\alpha x_n^2+2\beta x_n(1-x_n)+\gamma(1-x_n)^2 \Big]  \\ 
=\alpha x_n+\beta (1-x_n) - \alpha x_n^2-2\beta x_n(1-x_n)-\gamma(1-x_n)^2  \\
=\alpha x_n( 1-x_n) + \beta(1-x_n)(1-2x_n)-\gamma(1-x_n)^2 \\
=(1-x_n)(\alpha x_n+\beta -2\beta x_n -\gamma (1-x_n) ) \\
= (1-x_n) \Big( (\alpha- \beta) x_n + (\beta -\gamma)- (\beta -\gamma)x_n \Big)  \\
=(1-x_n)\Big( (\alpha- \beta) x_n+(\beta -\gamma)(1- x_n ) \Big)  \geq  0
\end{align}
As required. 
I  hope this helps you.